# passing data from loop to front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, ejs

I have this function on my backend:

```
   app.get('/dashboard', async(req, res) => {
  const customers = await stripe.customers.list();

  customers.data.forEach(customer => {
    console.log(customer.metadata);
  });

  res.render('dashboard.ejs', {customer: customers})
})
```

and on my front end:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
        <th>ACTIONS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% if(customer.length){ 
        for(var i = 0;i < customer.length;i++) { %>
      <tr>
      <td><%=customer[i].NAME%></td>
      <td><%=customer[i].EMAIL%></td>
         <% }
        }else{ %>
            <% } %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

however, i am trying to pass the `METADATA` to the front end. and within the metadata object, i have `name` and `email`. So on the front end, i tried:

```
<%=customer[i].METADATA.NAME%>
```

but it returned nothing. and same on the backend. how can i fix this?

Comment: whats the error you get? ```undefiened``` or ```error 404, 404, 500 ...```

Comment: @seriously no error. It just doesn't return anything. it's empty. but when i log `customers.data.forEach(customer => {
    console.log(customer.metadata);
  });`, then it shows the metadata, but now I need to get that metadata to the front end

Comment: In Javascript, Object keys are case sensitive, you said you have `name` and `email` in your data but in the template you used `.NAME` and `.EMAIL`

Comment: Can you verify data back? Also why set the stripe data to customers to the send back a single customer. Wouldn’t it be better to send back customers? Can you edit to post what the data is supposed to look like?

Comment: try printing the full object in ejs <%= customer%>

Comment: Also you’re missing </tr>

Comment: @Senthil when i try to do that, nothing shows up still. that's strange ...

Comment: The way I build my apis I fetch my data on the front end then loop through it but I don't see any fetch here. I dont get how you are accessing ```customer``` on the front end?

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ on the backend, i can verify that when i log `customers`, the entire data set comes back. I see all the info i need to. when i pass it through to the front end, i can't get any of it

Comment: @seriously i am passing the data from the backend to the front-end through the variable `customer`. well, at least it should be, but that's where im running into the issue. But don't really think I need a fetch because I am passing the data from the backend there

Comment: oh you need to fetch for sure. i will try to add a code blow of how to fetch .

Answer (score 0):

In the comments above, by fetch I mean the term fetch you need to some how connect to your backend to accept the data on front end. You can use ajax, axios, fetch API etc.... Below I used ajax to show how to get data from back end. Feel free to comment if you have any questions?

```js
var data_from_backend;

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'data_to_send_to_backend',
  url: 'server_URL',
  success: function(getMetadata) {
    $.each(JSON.parse(getMetadata), function(myMetadata) {
      data_from_backend = myMetadata.the_name_of_data_set_on_backend
    })
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log('Something went wrong.');
  }
});

console.log(data_from_backend)
```

Comment: understood. thanks for your answer. i am going to try this solution to see if it works for me. appreciate it

Comment: Got you. And make sure to check out how to handle your request on the back end too. Google node js restful api examples there are really easy ways of doing it.

Comment: will do, thanks. It will be beneficial to check it out because the way you did it makes sense to me, but I wouldn't be able to break it down and understand it properly. Appreciate the advice. I've got some learning to do this evening lol!

Comment: without jquery you can likely use `fetch` from a front end or the even the devtools console